# drawing a complete circle in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, swing

i searched a function that let me draw a circle in a 2d Array.
I found that the best way is to use the mathematical equation of the circumference, so i used it.

[math equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llF8i.png)

With this code i only get 1/4 of a circle and i don't know how to "Complete" it.

[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHhfq.png)
**Objective**: Draw a circle around the pressed button

```
            System.out.println("\nwait button pression\n");
            while(true){
                if(premuto.get()==true){
                    if(pos!=null){
                        if(pos.length()!=0){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i1=this.getIntI();//get the coordinates of the button pressed
            j1=this.getIntJ();// " 

            if(unita[i1][j1]!=null){ //control if the posistion isnt empty

                int ir=i1-unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange();//calculate the 00 point of the square .see image "array"
                int jr=j1-unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange();

                ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(MyFrame.class.getResource("test.png"));

                for (int i=ir ; i<(ir+(unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange()*2)) ; i++){
                    for (int j=jr ; j<(jr+unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange()*2) ;j++){//1st edit, changed the condition 
                        if(((i - i1) * (i - i1) + (j - j1) * (j - j1)) <= unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange() * unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange()){
                            btnArray[i][j].setIcon(icon);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

i'll hope you understand. thanks for the help.

1st EDIT:
first im gonna thanks to Yossi Vainshtein: if i set the condition
`i< ir + (unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange()*2)`
the program create a half circle, so i changed the 2 FOR conditions and it works but not perfectly. here's an image: check first image.

Conclusion: now it works with the 2 FOR conditions :
`i<= ir + (unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange()*2)`

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why dont use Graphics2D.drawOval()

Comment: You haven't told us what `pos` is so there's no way to know why the loop exits prematurely.

Comment: Only because it draw a graphic circle/oval and I need values for making controls or calculations

Comment: Circle drawing is a classic problem and has been solved quite efficiently https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: sorry to patrick, pos is a string that contain the position (i,j or x,y) of the button pressed on the btnArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your loop condition has a bug, shouldn't it be

```
 for (int i=ir ; i< ir + (unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange()*2) ; i++){
     for (int j=jr ; j< jr + (unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange()*2) ; j++){
           if (...) {
              ...
           }
     }
 }
```

You start with `ir` but you want to make `(unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange()*2)` steps, so the condition should be `i< ir + (unita[i1][j1].getAtkRange()*2)`

Comment: ehy, thanks! now it seems working but not perfectly. Read the edited question for more details.

Comment: looks like an off-by-one issue, try to the change the `<` to `<=`